# Hadoop Nodemanager not working in windows

Tags: windows, hadoop, selectsinglenode, nodemanager

I have installed single node cluster of Hadoop on my windows PC. All the services are working fine except for nodemanager. It is throwing error and shutting down. Here is the error:

> **2021-06-18 11:00:33,907 ERROR nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/nativeio/NativeIO$POSIX$Stat;**

Full error:

> 2021-06-21 11:53:09,859 ERROR nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/nativeio/NativeIO$POSIX$Stat;
> at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Native Method)
> at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.getStat(NativeIO.java:460)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfoByNativeIO(RawLocalFileSystem.java:821)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:735)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:703)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.initializeLocalDir(ResourceLocalizationService.java:1432)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.initializeLocalDirs(ResourceLocalizationService.java:1402)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.serviceInit(ResourceLocalizationService.java:260)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:108)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceInit(ContainerManagerImpl.java:323)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:108)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:516)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:974)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:1054)
> 2021-06-21 11:53:09,863 INFO service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService failed in state STOPPED
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.replaceNode(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1106)
> at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1097)
> at java.util.Collections$SetFromMap.remove(Collections.java:5514)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.deregisterDirsChangeListener(DirectoryCollection.java:221)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService.deregisterLocalDirsChangeListener(LocalDirsHandlerService.java:271)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.serviceStop(ResourceLocalizationService.java:426)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceStop(ContainerManagerImpl.java:720)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStop(NodeManager.java:526)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:67)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService$CompositeServiceShutdownHook.run(CompositeService.java:184)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> 2021-06-21 11:53:09,864 WARN service.CompositeService: When stopping the service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.replaceNode(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1106)
> at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1097)
> at java.util.Collections$SetFromMap.remove(Collections.java:5514)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.deregisterDirsChangeListener(DirectoryCollection.java:221)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService.deregisterLocalDirsChangeListener(LocalDirsHandlerService.java:271)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.serviceStop(ResourceLocalizationService.java:426)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceStop(ContainerManagerImpl.java:720)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStop(NodeManager.java:526)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:67)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService$CompositeServiceShutdownHook.run(CompositeService.java:184)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> 2021-06-21 11:53:09,865 INFO service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl failed in state STOPPED
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.replaceNode(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1106)
> at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1097)
> at java.util.Collections$SetFromMap.remove(Collections.java:5514)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.deregisterDirsChangeListener(DirectoryCollection.java:221)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService.deregisterLocalDirsChangeListener(LocalDirsHandlerService.java:271)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.serviceStop(ResourceLocalizationService.java:426)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceStop(ContainerManagerImpl.java:720)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStop(NodeManager.java:526)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:67)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService$CompositeServiceShutdownHook.run(CompositeService.java:184)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> 2021-06-21 11:53:09,865 WARN service.CompositeService: When stopping the service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.replaceNode(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1106)
> at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1097)
> at java.util.Collections$SetFromMap.remove(Collections.java:5514)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.deregisterDirsChangeListener(DirectoryCollection.java:221)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService.deregisterLocalDirsChangeListener(LocalDirsHandlerService.java:271)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.serviceStop(ResourceLocalizationService.java:426)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceStop(ContainerManagerImpl.java:720)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStop(NodeManager.java:526)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:67)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService$CompositeServiceShutdownHook.run(CompositeService.java:184)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> 2021-06-21 11:53:09,866 INFO service.AbstractService: Service NodeManager failed in state STOPPED
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.replaceNode(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1106)
> at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1097)
> at java.util.Collections$SetFromMap.remove(Collections.java:5514)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.deregisterDirsChangeListener(DirectoryCollection.java:221)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService.deregisterLocalDirsChangeListener(LocalDirsHandlerService.java:271)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.serviceStop(ResourceLocalizationService.java:426)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceStop(ContainerManagerImpl.java:720)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStop(NodeManager.java:526)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:67)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService$CompositeServiceShutdownHook.run(CompositeService.java:184)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> 2021-06-21 11:53:09,867 WARN service.AbstractService: When stopping the service NodeManager
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.replaceNode(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1106)
> at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1097)
> at java.util.Collections$SetFromMap.remove(Collections.java:5514)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.deregisterDirsChangeListener(DirectoryCollection.java:221)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService.deregisterLocalDirsChangeListener(LocalDirsHandlerService.java:271)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.serviceStop(ResourceLocalizationService.java:426)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceStop(ContainerManagerImpl.java:720)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStop(NodeManager.java:526)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:67)
> at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService$CompositeServiceShutdownHook.run(CompositeService.java:184)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> 2021-06-21 11:53:09,867 INFO nodemanager.NodeManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG:

This error goes on and on but that's the main part of it causing the error. What can be a way around?

Comment: please provide full error message.

Comment: I've edited the question with full error message.